# Radio button selection - hide and show fields

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a simple Hide/Show effect, depending on what radio button is checked.
It's not working correctly and I'm not sure why.
I want the hidden table (`#reprint_oui`)to `SHOW` when the user clicks "Oui"...and hide if "Non" is selected.

Here's my JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("input[name$='reprint_group']").click(function(){

var radio_value = $(this).val();

if(radio_value=='Oui') {
    $("#reprint_oui").show("slow");
}
else if(radio_value=='Non') {
   $("#reprint_oui").show("slow");
   }
  });

$("#reprint_oui").hide();

});​
```

Here's my HTML :

```
<h2>Fiche technique de production</h2>
      <table width="100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="80%">Avons-nous par le passé produit des affiches que vous vous apprêtez à commander?</td>
            <td width="20%"><label for="oui_reprint">Oui</label>
            <input name="reprint_group" type="radio" id="oui_reprint" value="Oui">
            <label for="non_newprint">Non</label>
            <input type="radio" name="reprint_group" id="non_newprint" value="Non"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table width="100%" border="0" id="reprint_oui">
        <tr>
          <td width="80%">S'agit-il d'une réimpression sans changement?</td>
          <td width="20%"><label for="oui_reprint">Oui</label>
            <input type="radio" name="reprint_sans_changement" id="oui_reprint" value="Oui">
            <label for="non_newprint">Non</label>
            <input type="radio" name="reprint_sans_changement" id="non_newprint" value="Non"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25KkU/)

Thank you

Comment: You should never have elements on your page that have the same id, that will cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually `show`ing the table when the radio value is `Non`. Change it to `hide()` instead:

```
if (radio_value == 'Oui') {
  $("#reprint_oui").show("slow");
} else if(radio_value == 'Non') {
  $("#reprint_oui").hide("slow"); // you have show() here
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/25KkU/2/)**.

Answer (score 0):

The results of both if-else SHOW the reprint_oui element.

Hide the element when "Non"

http://jsfiddle.net/25KkU/1/

**Also make sure you use triple "=" when comparing in javascript:**

```
if(a===b)
{}
```